# Start child process with subprocess.Popen and read its output while it is running

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing, subprocess, pipe

I have a command whose output I am writing to a file and using `subprocess.Popen` to call the command. Here is a sample:

```
stdout_output = open('testfile.txt','w')
process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=stdout_output,shell=True)
stdout_read = open('testfile.txt','r')
data = stdout_read.read()
print data
```

The data sometimes has nothing in it but when I add some sleep between triggering the process and reading it for e.g

```
stdout_output = open('testfile.txt','w')
process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=stdout_output,shell=True)
time.sleep(3)
stdout_read = open('testfile.txt','r')
data = stdout_read.read()
print data
```

Then the data contains the actual data written in the file. Is there something which I am missing here. Or is there any other way to add some time between triggering the process and reading the output instead of giving the hard-coded sleep.

*Note* - The command is an ongoing process. I cannot add `process.wait()` or cannot wait for the process to finish before reading the file.

Comment: can't you read line by line using a loop?

Answer (score 3):

`Popen` starts a new process that runs concurrently, so if you want to reliably obtain the output of that process then yes you **must** wait for the process. In fact the `subprocess` module has a [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function that does this for you:

```
data = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
print data
```

Obviously this is blocking.

---

The **only** way to "wait" the end of a process without blocking your main process is to [`poll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) it. However this requires that you write your code in such a way that you periodically check and when the `poll` method returns something different from `None` you can read the output of the process.

For example:

```
def do_stuff(proc, filename):
    # proc.poll() check if proc has ended
    while proc.poll() is None:
        print('Here you do whatever you want while you wait for the process')
        # do other stuff
        ping_pong.play()
    # here we are sure the command terminate and wrote his output
    proc.stdout.close()
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read()

stdout_file = open('some_file', 'w')
process = Popen(['command'], stdout=stdout_file)
output = do_stuff(process, 'some_file')
```

Depending on what you are doing you may need to structure your code differently.

Comment: This is blocking so I cannot use this approach.

Comment: @user3551262 You cannot read a process output if you do not wait till the end... The only thing you can do is to `poll` the process until it ended...

Comment: This may work. But opening a file, creating process that writes to it, and then passing file name to a function that opens same file but for reading and returns file content. Seems like a not very clean way to do it. In the end, part where file content reading is done is still blocked until process is done.

Comment: @ikac You cannot a read a file from the future, that's obvious and is what I have already tried to say to the OP. The best thing you can do is do something else until "future happens" and you can finally read the file. Obviously doing this is asynchronous programming which probably requires some major refactoring of the Op code, and without that code I could only post a fake example.

Answer (score 1):

Buffering might be an issue.

Try opening file for writing with zero length buffer. Like this:

```
stdout_output = open('testfile.txt','w', 0)
```

Of course, command might not immediately produce an output in which case you will have to need to have a loop for constantly trying to read.

### Example with pipes

Since you want to have ability to read immediately after starting process, what you can use is `Pipe`. `subprocess.Popen` already gives you an option to put `stdint/stdout/stderr` through it.

Here is an example Python code with sample `bash` script that echoes message, sleeps and then echoes another message. Pay attention that Python code has to know when child process is done sending data.

```
import subprocess

"""
notifier.sh
------------------

echo "This is me"
sleep 4
echo "This is me again"

------------------
"""

command = ['bash', 'notifier.sh']
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    if process.poll() is not None:
        break
    data = process.stdout.readline()
    print data
```

I did try to mimic use case with this sample `bash` shell script.

Also, I did remove `shell=True` because I'm not sure if there is a really good reason for using it, but it is a big security issue.

Comment: It looks like you need a 'pipe' between process and the rest of Python code? Am I right? Since you open same file for writing and then immediately for reading. This probably messes up the whole writing by the process running.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample on this

Answer (score 0):

If you wish not to wait till the end of the execution, one of the options is to read in a separate thread:

```
def reader(fd, finished):
    while not finished.is_set():
        data = fd.read()
        if data: print(data)
        time.sleep(SOME_TIMEOUT)

process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=stdout_output,shell=True)
finished = threading.Event()
reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=reader, args=(stdout_output, finished))
reader_thread.start()
process.wait()
finished.set()
reader_thread.join()
```

Comment: Instead of using threading I can just use a while loop and put a timeout to it until it returns me the proper output.